# How to make post build batch file commands run in a single terminal?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, iar

When building an embedded project using the IAR Embedded Workbench IDE, we use a batch file with multiple post-processing commands (ELF executable parsers/filters) to generate our final loadable image.

The problem is that it seems like every tool invocation opens a new terminal window, runs there briefly and closes, effectively eliminating the possibility to track its messages.

When directing the master batch file's output to a file, it records only the commands of the batch file, but it does not capture the screen output of the programs invoked by it.

Trying to precede the batch name with `cmd /k`, like:

```
cmd /k post_build.bat arg1 arg2 > out.txt
```

did not change the behaviour.

How can I capture the programs' output (w/o redirecting per-program, as there are multiple of them and it will awefully clutter the batch file)?

**Update**: The basic command line looked like this:

```
post_build.bat arg1 arg2 > out.txt
```

While trying, I tried the the following variants:

```
post_build.bat arg1 arg2 > out.txt 2>&1
cmd /k post_build.bat arg1 arg2 > out.txt
cmd /k post_build.bat arg1 arg2 > out.txt 2>&1
```

The batch contains invocations of executable programs (not other batch files). These programs do some processing according to the `arg*` arguments. Some of the programs generate output to the terminal, as well as working on other files. Basically, assume the batch file looks like:

```
prog1 arg1
prog2 arg2 out2
copy out2 out3
echo Done processing files!
```

Comment: How are those post-processing commands executed? Can you post some lines of the batch to see how it is running the tools?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting only :

```
post_build.bat arg1 arg2
```

as post build command? In my case it seems to be working without calling `cmd`.